# Client communication with Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

Can an Amazon EC2 instance process requests from and return results to an external client which may a browser or non-browser application? (I know that the EC2 instance will require a IP address and must be able to create a socket and bind to a port in order to do this.)

I'm considering an Amazon EC2 instance because the server application is not written in PHP, Ruby or any other language that conventional web hosting services support by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it will. Just setup the security group the right way to allow your clients to connect.

Take a look at this guide: [Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Security Groups](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

Also keep in mind: It's not possible to change the policy group after you created the EC2 instance. This feature is available for VPC instances only. See http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/#S2 for more information.